# Could not find property 'classpath' on task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

I have to use Lambda expression in my application but I could not achieve this problem.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

PS : Using Android Studio 2.2 latest, SDK Manager up to date and Java v1.8 installed.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I found that problem occurs when I use ButterKnife. Now I use following lines and works well.

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Have you used realm or apt ,etc?